# WP7 PivotControl Spacing

Tags: windows-phone-7, spacing

How to set spacing between PivotItems headers in PivotControl? I'm working on tabbed design, I was able to customize pivotItems headers
with icons but I don't know how to set spacing between them.

here's my xaml:

```
  <controls:Pivot Title="Tabs" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,0,0" Width="480" Margin="0,0,0,0">

        <!--Pivot item one-->
        <controls:PivotItem Name="tab1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0">
            <controls:PivotItem.Header >
                <ContentControl>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#787878" Width="150">
                        <Image Source="Images/tab_home.png" Height="80" Width="80"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="Listen" FontSize="32" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ContentControl>
            </controls:PivotItem.Header>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (should) only have one pivot control on a page.

If you are talking about the spacing between the PivotItem Headers then as per your example can you not just set a `Margin` on the StackPanel you are putting in the header?

```
<controls:PivotItem>
    <controls:PivotItem.Header>
        <ContentControl>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#787878" Width="150" Margin="20,0,20,0">
                <Image Source="Images/tab_home.png" Height="80" Width="80"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Listen" FontSize="32" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ContentControl>
    </controls:PivotItem.Header>
```

This adds 20 pixels to the left and right of the header.

If this isn't what you're after can you please update your question. I'd recommentd adding mock ups of what you're trying to achieve too.

Comment: yes that's it, Margin="0,0,-10,0" in PivotItem.Header StackPanel works perfectly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should post you xaml, but usually most UI Elements have a `Margin` property